# How to call to Java RMI methods from web client?

Tags: java, reactjs, rmi

I have a Java RMI application developed  with Swing GUI interface. I want to change that to React app. Is it possible to call RMI methods from JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if so, what?

Comment: No not yet , I will try to create a rest API with spring boot to call RMI methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you can use hessian protocol (reimplement RMI with hessian, just delegate from hessian servlet to local RMI). Use hessian.js

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. Javascript is not Java at all.
You may consider to rewrite server side of RMI application to either Webservice or REST API application, then you'll be able to call its methods from Javascript. It can be also just a small wrapper application around existing RMI.
Like:

**Javascript call (SOAP or REST) -> Wrapper call (RMI) -> Existing RMI app.**

Comment: its clear java is not java script, i want to call rmi from javascript , the same as we work with rest apis

Comment: @SidaliHallak RMI is Java. Your question is about JavaScript. JavaScript is not Java and it certainly doesn't include RMI. Answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @user207421 I finally use hessian.js as Kliment Simoncev suggested, this is the correct answer.